# Is there a way to subscribe to any emit event on Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, frontend

I've got an app that uses socket.io for frontend-backend communication. I've got multiple instances of the `socket.emit()` function throughout the codebase, and I'd like to know if it's possible to get a notification whenever an `emit` happens. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
socket.on('emit', function() {
    // do something
})
```

I haven't been able to find anything like this in the docs, though. Is it possible?

EDIT: Of course this will alert me whenever somebody emits an event with the `'emit'` string. I want to be notified if ANY string is used.

Comment: I haven't seen any such functionality either. But to circumvent it, can you emit another signal from within each of your emit. Then you can handle this emit signal separately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any functionality like that, but what you can try is, emit an additional common event whenever you are emitting a event, for example

```
socket.emit("common", "required data here");
```

Whenever you are emitting an event. That way, every time an event occurs, you are also emitting the "common" event, which you can then catch.

So, you can then use `socket.on("common", function(){});` every time an emit occurs.

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

To send the data to everyone connected to the socket you need something like this:::

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);    
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.emit('status', 'Send this to everyone connected!');


 });
```